# Retro Pi expand filesystem keeps reverting

Tags: filesystem, retropie

I have gone through the steps to setup a retro pie on raspberry pi 2 with a 32 gb sd card and am having difficulty with the expand filesystem.

I expand the file system through using raspi-config (have tried doing this through both menu and command line).
I then restart as per the prompt and turn off the machine.

I insert the SD card into my machine to transer roms but it has reverted to 50mb partition.

Is there a step I am missing?

These are the instructions I am following:
https://github.com/retropie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki

Here is a screenshot of df command line output:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS is on the machine  you using to transfer the roms?

Comment: I am transferring from osx to retro pie. I use apple pi baker to setup the image on sd. When expanded, restarted and re inserted into my mac it is still a 60mb partition.

Comment: AFAIK there is little fat32 boot partition and after that there is system partition ;) can you add `df` output from Pi?

Comment: I have added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSX machine is only reading the very small FAT32 boot partition.  The rest of the SD card is a linux ext4 partition and it looks like it has been resized properly.

OSX can't read the ext4 partition natively. I think there may be software to let you mount the ext4 filesystem on OSX but I don't know.

Comment: I feel so stupid. When I first inserted the SD card I was able to see both partitions, one of which disappeared. This must have been a fluke. As this question is more to do with my error am I best to delete this question from the stack exchange?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your setup. The filesystem is expanded.

If you want to transfer roms do it using the preinstalled SMB connection or the preconfigured USB key transfer method (read about it on petrockblog or the googlez)

Just putting the SD card in a computer that doesn't automatically mount linux EXT3/4 partitions won't do since you will most likely only see a very tiny boot partition formatted in FAT.